# Deploying Liferay Theme on a WebLogic Server

Tags: themes, liferay, weblogic

Is their any standard way to deploy a custom Liferay Theme on a Web Logic Server? I can't seem to find any documentation on such a task, and it is proving difficult trying to figure it out on my own.

Thanks for any tips mates!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you Liferay Plugin SDK setup for your server. Where you will need to create / update build.{username}.properties file with Web Logic Configuration in it. You can get properties from build.properties file and copy those to your build.{username}.properties which will have your Web Logic server path. Once you have this set properly when you deploy theme within Liferay plugin SDK it should deploy automatically.

Below link I could fine for Installing liferay on WebLogic 
http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen11-installing-liferay-on-oracle-weblogic-103-0

Hope this help you !